# Open the link in new tab instead of the default action of a bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-5

I am using a bootstrap [MyResume](https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/MyResume/)

And there is this section
[image: The section that opens a modal and displays the link in it]

This is the piece of code for it

```html
<div class="row portfolio-container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>App 1</h4>
                <p>App</p>
                <div class="portfolio-links">
                  <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="App 1"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="portfolio-details.html" class="portfolio-details-lightbox" data-glightbox="type: external" title="Portfolio Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Web 3</h4>
                <p>Web</p>
                <div class="portfolio-links">
                  <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-2.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="Web 3"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="portfolio-details.html" class="portfolio-details-lightbox" data-glightbox="type: external" title="Portfolio Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>App 2</h4>
                <p>App</p>
                <div class="portfolio-links">
                  <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-3.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="App 2"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="portfolio-details.html" class="portfolio-details-lightbox" data-glightbox="type: external" title="Portfolio Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-card">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Card 2</h4>
                <p>Card</p>
                <div class="portfolio-links">
                  <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-4.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="Card 2"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="portfolio-details.html" class="portfolio-details-lightbox" data-glightbox="type: external" title="Portfolio Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-5.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Web 2</h4>
                <p>Web</p>
                <div class="portfolio-links">
                  <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-5.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="Web 2"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="portfolio-details.html" class="portfolio-details-lightbox" data-glightbox="type: external" title="Portfolio Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-6.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>App 3</h4>
                <p>App</p>
                <div class="portfolio-links">
                  <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-6.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="App 3"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="portfolio-details.html" class="portfolio-details-lightbox" data-glightbox="type: external" title="Portfolio Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-card">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-7.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Card 1</h4>
                <p>Card</p>
                <div class="portfolio-links">
                  <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-7.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="Card 1"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="portfolio-details.html" class="portfolio-details-lightbox" data-glightbox="type: external" title="Portfolio Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-card">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-8.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Card 3</h4>
                <p>Card</p>
                <div class="portfolio-links">
                  <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-8.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="Card 3"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="portfolio-details.html" class="portfolio-details-lightbox" data-glightbox="type: external" title="Portfolio Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-9.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Web 3</h4>
                <p>Web</p>
                <div class="portfolio-links">
                  <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-9.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="Web 3"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="portfolio-details.html" class="portfolio-details-lightbox" data-glightbox="type: external" title="Portfolio Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
```

What I am trying to do is provide a link in the href of the element that I have rounded, like this

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-app">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>App 1</h4>
                <p>App</p>
                <div class="portfolio-links">
                  <a href="assets/img/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="App 1"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                  <a href="https://www.google.com/" target='_blank' onclick="this.click()" class="portfolio-details-lightbox" data-glightbox="type: external" title="Portfolio Details"><i class="bx bx-link"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

What I want now are two solutions here, when I click on the link button

1. Open the link in a new tab.
2. Open the link in the modal that pops up when clicked on it (default operation of the template).

First, I tried putting `target="_blank"` which didn't work, then I tried to control the effect by using `onclick="this.click()"` in the element itself, which didn't work either. Then I thought that it was being prevented by the vendor js overwriting the inline `onclick`, so then I tried to pinpoint the js code that was controlling the modal pop-up, which I managed to find but then as I am still learning js so couldn't make any changes that work the way I want.
The name and path of the js file is `assets\vendor\glightbox\js\glightbox.js` in the project folder.
I have integrated all this in a Django framework, but I don't think it's a Django issue, but still mentioning it because in the end, I want all of this to work with Django.

Also please explain your answer on how it's working.
Thank you :)